# how to reach another two containers with cpprest from a dockerised nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

i have 2 docker containers with cpprest runned in:
`docker run -it -p 0.0.0.0:8081:8080`
and
`docker run -it -p 0.0.0.0:8082:8080`

I have nginx in docker container runned in: `docker run -it -p 0.0.0.0:8083:8080`

my nginx.conf file is:

```
http {
   upstream backend {
      server 0.0.0.0:8081;
      server 0.0.0.0:8082;
   }

   # This server accepts all traffic to port 80 and passes it to the upstream. 
   # Notice that the upstream name and the proxy_pass need to match.

   server {
      listen 80;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://backend/;
      }
   }
}
```

When nginx isn't in a container all works fine, but when i try with dockerised nginx and open 0.0.0.0:8083 - it gives me :
[image]

Comment: Create the network and use external network in the main container

Comment: I think you will have to use docker-compose.